# Crop MP3 to last N seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, avconv

I want to generate a new (fully valid) MP3 file from an existing MP3 file. The new file should only contain the last N seconds of the track.

There's `-t` option in `avconv` for getting first N seconds:

> -t duration (output)
>
> Stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration.  duration may be a number in seconds, or in "hh:mm:ss[.xxx]" form.

Is there an option to crop last N seconds? `avconv` is not requirement in my case, all other tools are acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `ffprobe` to get the duration of the audio.

```
ffprobe -i input_audio -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

Calculate nth_second and use it with `ffmpeg`

```
ffmpeg -i input_audio -ss nth_second output_file
```

Following is the shell script for the process.

```
#!/bin/bash
duration=$(ffprobe -i ${1} -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")
nth_second=$(echo "${duration} - ${2}"|bc)
ffmpeg -i ${1} -ss ${nth_second} ${3}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to release the script, you should check to ensure mp3info is installed, and the argument count, etc. but this should get you started. Save it as a .sh and call it with `mp3lastnsecs.sh input.mp3 output.mp3 numsecs`

Also, you'll need to add the other ffmpeg flags for tagging, bitrate, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

SECS=$(mp3info -p "%S" $1)
if [ "$SECS" -ge "$3" ]; then
  START=$((SECS-$3))
else
  echo 'Error: requested length is longer than the song.'
  exit 1
fi

#echo Starting song $1 from $START seconds.
ffmpeg -i "$1" -ss $START "$2"
```

Sample output:

```
[  @  tmp] ./lastN.sh 01-glaube.mp3 output.mp3 20
Starting song 01-glaube.mp3 from 96 seconds.
ffmpeg -i 01-glaube.mp3 -ss 96 output.mp3 # I had an echo in there for testing, it now calls ffmpeg directly
[  @  tmp] ./lastN.sh 01-glaube.mp3 output.mp3 1234
Error: requested length is longer than the song.
```